# Custom Variable get_post_meta is returning a blank value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/
I followed a tutorial on how to create custom fields for product variations. This worked, however now I am trying to export custom fields data into the email customizer template file.

My attempt to do this output a blank value; "array(0) { }"
Note: "$product_idMe" is working, and puts in the correct product ID.

```
$product_attr2 = get_post_meta( $product_idMe, '_variable_loc');

echo var_dump( $product_attr2 );
```

Here is the original  tutorial code to get the custom variables working in the Wordpress admin, if that helps to reference how it was made:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_variable_loc[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'Inv Location', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_variable_loc', true )
        )
    );



function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $variable_loc = $_POST['_variable_loc'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $variable_loc) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_variable_loc', esc_attr( $variable_loc ) );
    }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );


function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {

    $variations['text_field'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_text_field', true );

    return $variations;
}
```

Comment: Additional info:
$product_idMe = $item->get_product_id();

I’m thinking part of the issue is not designating the “variation_id”

Is there a way to do: get_post_meta( $product_idMe,$variations[ ‘variation_id’ ], ‘_variable_loc’);

Comment: My recent attempts, with no success:

Attempt#1.
$product_attr = get_post_meta( $product_variations[$product_idMe] , '_variable_mlt', true );  
echo $product_attr;

Attempt #2.
$product_attr = get_post_meta( $product_variations->$product_idMe , '_variable_mlt', true );  
echo $product_attr;
.........................

-Thanks in advance, Michael.